# How to draw makers overlaying axis with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is the effect I want.

[image]

But I get the figure below, in which the marker is covered by the axis. If the left yaxis is set to invisible, only half the marker is displayed.

[image]

Comment: Picture 1 is the first line 'enter image description here', and Picture 2 is the end 'enter image description here'. I am new here and I don't know how to show my pictures. Wish your help, thank you.

Comment: What do you have so far? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn the clipping off, set `clip_on = False`, refer to [official doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on).

Comment: I've tried and it didn't work. ```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [1,2,8,16,32,12,3,4]
plt.plot(a, marker = 's')
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_clip_on(False)
ax.set_xlim(0,7)   here is my code. I don't know how to change lines. Excuse and thank you.

Comment: I got it. I used the following statments and it worked.Thanks a lot.
line, = plt.plot(a, marker = 's')
line.set_clip_on(False)